# To Cucumber(or other bdd) or not to Cucumber when automating api tests?

Tags: automated-testing, api, rest-assured, cucumber-java

I want to know you’re opinion about your experience with Cucumber when automating api tests. Would you recommend it in all cases? I’m dealing with a very complex endpoint(complex request/response) and quite different test cases and I find difficult to “standardise” steps to be reusable to other test cases. Also passing along different parameters from one step to another is quite difficult to manage(through scenario context) when reusing steps. What’s your approach in this? Did you find some efficient ways of using cucumber?

Answer (score -1):

Using natural language to describe scenarios is useful for
agents who use natural language (aka humans who don't code).

If you want to intensively involve these people, it may
remove a barrier of communication. You then define the natural language scenarios in code. If the cost of the later is smaller than the advantage than the former, it makes sense.

On the other hand, if all people involved would understand code, you can describe the scenarios directly in code; thus reducing the [accidental complexity](https://medium.com/background-thread/accidental-and-essential-complexity-programming-word-of-the-day-b4db4d2600d4) of your solution.

[image]